# What happens with the data of a synchronized data extension when the synchronization is paused?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder, data-synchronization

I would like to know what happens with the records of a synchronized data extension when the source object sync is paused.

It looks like the sync data until the paused time still remains but, is there a way to delete or clear that sync data extension?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pause or modify a Synchronized Data Extension from the Marketing Cloud, it doesn't end the synchronization processing that runs automatically behind the scenes.  The workaround is to end new updates from being pushed to the Data Extension object that's no longer needed, or needs to be reset.

The below instructions outline the best method of resetting the data and fields within a specific object and the best method for ending synchronization of a specific object when needed.

[Remove or Reset Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000233120&type=1)

> **Note:** When certain fields are no longer needed, removing these select fields within the Data Source configuration will result in
>   those fields, and any data within, being deleted from the Synchronized
>   data extension when the Poll Schedule runs it's next cycle.

1. Go to Contact Builder.
2. Click Data Sources | Synchronized.
3. Select your Salesforce Organization as the Data Source.
4. Under the Synchronized tab, select the Salesforce Object that you wish to modify.
5. Click Edit Fields.
6. Uncheck any fields that are no longer needed (some defaults can not be edited).
7. Click Save.

**Note:** If the 'X field will be removed and un-synchronized' message appears, click Continue. Then, click Resume Sync and click OK.